# Changing the css class name for another control click event

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, html

```
 <ul class="submenu">
       <li class="lstnetdays"><a href="NetDaysInAR.html">Net Days In AR</a></li>
```

Hi, I have ul and li tags, My requirement is when i click on the li tag i want to change the ul class name as "submenunew".

Comment: are you using jquery or pure javascript?

Comment: i am using javascript.

Comment: Can you post your javascript as well so we can see what you've tried so far?

Comment: your approach seems to be a little bit off. There are better ways to do what you're trying to achieve. Can you tell us why you want to change the class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

HTML

```
<ul class="submenu">
    <li>Net Days In AR 1</li>
    <li>Net Days In AR 2</li>
    <li>Net Days In AR 3</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function () {
        this.parentNode.className = "submenunew";
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().attr('class', 'submenunew');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Select li using class name and add event handler

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("lstnetdays").onclick = function () {
            this.parentNode.className = "submenunew";
        }
```